# Object error in python 3.4 in code

Tags: python

I keep getting this error:

```
<__main__.product object at 0x0231A7B0>
```

from the code:

```
    def prnt(self): 
        print("\n**********************************************************")
        print(self.prntlist()) 
        print("Grand total\t\t\t\t$", self.setprice())
        print("**********************************************************\n")

    def prntlist(self):
        x = ''
        for i in self.cartlist:
            x = i, "/n"
        return x
```

instead of executing the function prntlist it displays that error

full code:

```
class product(object):
    name = ''
    price = 0

    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def prnt(self):
        print("\n**********************************************************")
        print("Item\t\t\t   Price")
        print(self.name,"............ $", self.price)
        print("\n**********************************************************")

    def prntline(self):
        x = self.name + ".........." + self.price
        return x

class cart(object):
    totalprice = 0
    cartlist = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.totalprice = totalprice
        self.cartlist = []

    def setprice(self):
        totprice = self.totalprice
        for i in self.cartlist:
            self.totalprice += i.price
        return totprice

    def prnt(self): 
        print("\n**********************************************************")
        print(self.prntlist())
        print("Grand total\t\t\t\t$", self.setprice())
        print("**********************************************************\n")

    def prntlinecart(self):
        print("You have purchased: ", self.prntlist())

    def prntlist(self):
        x = ''
        for i in self.cartlist:
            x = i, "/n"
        return x

    def additem(self, item):
        self.cartlist.append(item)
        print("Ah, fresh out. But we can have it shipped to your house next week")
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is actually calling these methods? What you posted isn't an error...

Comment: This `x = i, "/n"` makes x as a tuple. not string. Dont know if this is causing your problem, but from your code it seems it should be str, not a tuple.

Comment: prntlist() isnt being exectued.

Comment: Can you provide example code that uses these classes, and how you call prntlist?

Comment: How would I make prntlist print out items from the list cartlist? Everything I've tried seems to give me an error

Comment: prntlist is only called in the prnt function, and thats called in the main program like this:
RL = product("Red Leicester", 13.99)
    mycart.additem(RL)
        RL.prnt()

Comment: `RL.prnt()` calles prnt function from product class. not from cart.

Comment: mycart.prnt() prints from cart   
how could I make it so that the cart class could access the product class

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made your example work for me, just to see what is happening:

```
class product(object):
    name = ''
    price = 0

    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def prnt(self):
        print("\n**********************************************************")
        print("Item\t\t\t   Price")
        print(self.name,"............ $", self.price)
        print("\n**********************************************************")

    def prntline(self):
        x = self.name + ".........." + self.price
        return x

class cart(object):
    totalprice = 0
    cartlist = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.totalprice = 0
        self.cartlist = []

    def setprice(self):
        totprice = self.totalprice
        for i in self.cartlist:
            self.totalprice += i.price
        return totprice

    def prnt(self): 
        print("\n**********************************************************")
        print(self.prntlist())
        print("Grand total\t\t\t\t$", self.setprice())
        print("**********************************************************\n")

    def prntlinecart(self):
        print("You have purchased: ", self.prntlist())

    def prntlist(self):
        x = ''
        print('fff')
        for i in self.cartlist:
            x = i, "/n"

        return x

    def additem(self, item):
        self.cartlist.append(item)
        print("Ah, fresh out. But we can have it shipped to your house next week")


mycart =       cart()  

RL = product("Red Leicester", 13.99)
RL.prnt()

mycart.additem(RL) 
mycart.prnt()
```

The output is:

```
**********************************************************
Item               Price
Red Leicester ............ $ 13.99

**********************************************************
Ah, fresh out. But we can have it shipped to your house next week

**********************************************************
fff
(<__main__.product object at 0x7ffbe52609e8>, '/n')
Grand total             $ 0
**********************************************************
```

It seems that you ask about this: `<__main__.product object at 0x7ffbe52609e8>`. As I wrote in the first comment, this is because you are making tuple, not a string when with the following line `x = i, "/n"`.